# MySQL Query ORDER BY DateTime Issue

Tags: mysql, sql, database, datetime

I'm trying to order the query by the latest update datetime greater than now ascending then less than now descending. This is my desired output:

```
2014-06-01 00:00:00
2014-06-04 00:00:00
2014-06-05 00:00:00
2014-06-06 00:00:00
2014-05-19 00:00:00
2014-05-15 00:00:00
0000-00-00 00:00:00
```

But Im getting this instead:

```
2014-06-01 00:00:00
2014-06-04 00:00:00
2014-06-05 00:00:00
2014-06-06 00:00:00
0000-00-00 00:00:00
2014-05-15 00:00:00
2014-05-19 00:00:00
```

The Query I'm using is this:

```
SELECT lastupdated FROM users ORDER BY lastupdated > NOW() DESC, lastupdated ASC;
```

Answer (score 2):

you can do it with `UNION`:

```
SELECT lastupdated 
FROM users 
WHERE lastupdated > NOW()
ORDER BY lastupdated  DESC

UNION

SELECT lastupdated 
FROM users 
WHERE lastupdated <= NOW()
ORDER BY lastupdated ASC;
```

Comment: Union has no bearing on the ordering of results.

Answer (score 1):

What is the problem?  The date `0000-00-00` is in the past, so it is listed first for that group.  If you want it last overall, put it there explicitly:

```
order by (case when lastupdated = '0000-00-00 00:00:00' then 1
               when lastupdate > now() then 2
               else 3
          end),
         lastupdated asc;
```

If you want the ordering to be descending for the last group, then do:

```
order by (lastupdate > now()) desc,
         (case when lastupdate > now() then lastupdate end) asc,
         lastupdate desc
```

Comment: The question isn't about the 0000-00-00 being out of place, it's about the last 3 dates being out of order regardless of what the actual value is.

Comment: @dagarrison . . . It obviously looked to me like the problem was the zero date being out of place.  Your comment helped me understand the question better.

Answer (score -1):

Explicitly sort timestamps < NOW() similar to how you're sorting > NOW()

```
SELECT lastupdated FROM users ORDER BY lastupdated > NOW() DESC, lastupdated <= NOW() ASC;
```

Comment: your order by now just has booleans, this won't sort by any date values.

Comment: @dagarrison not sure where all of these crazy booleans are, but this works.

Comment: it might coincidentally sort correctly, but this isn't doing any sorting based on a datetime.

Comment: @dagarrison not sure what you're basing that off of...lastUpdated is a timestamp that's being compared to NOW()...

Comment: you are first sorting by `(lastupdated > NOW())` which is a boolean. and then you are sorting by `(lastupdated < NOW())` which is a boolean (and is just the opposite value of the first boolean)